# Using JQuery to apply div class based on page?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I'm an application developer intern, tasked with styling the main layout for my companies new application. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to focus on the LI item based on the page. Currently it resets the drop down menu because there is nothing telling it to stay expanded.

[Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Wpu.jpg)

If I go to the View "Base Product Info", how can I tell the application to apply a div class "open close" to that li item? I'm using ASP.net

Sorry in advance if my explanation was not clear.

Comment: Please provide some relevant code of what you have tried so far and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, location js object contain info about current page address

check if opened needed page and add class...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPage = location.pathname;
  if(currentPage == '/products'){
    //select needed li item and add class open
    $('li.products').addClass('open');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```